# After sending data over a socket, it isn't being converted back to list

Tags: python, sockets, pickle

So I can send strings just fine. What I want to do though is to more or less send a string representation of a list. I know quite a few to convert a list into something that should be able to sent as a string and then converted back.

```
#on sending
l = [1,2,3,4]
l_str = str(l)

#on receiving 
l = ast.literal_eval(received_data)

## or pickle
l = pickle.dumps([1,2,3,4])

##then
l = pick.loads(received_data)
```

My issues however seems to be that something odd is happening between the receiving and sending.

Right now I have this

```
msg = pickle.dumps([sys.stdin.readline(), person])
s.send(msg)
```

where sys.stdin.readline() is the line typed into the console and person is a variable containing someone's name.

I then receive it like so.

```
d1 = sock.recv(4096)
pickles = False                
try:
    d1 = pickle.loads(d1)
    pickles = True
```

It doesn't matter if I just make the list string by my first method and then use ast.literal_eval or use pickle, it never actually converts back to the list I want.

I currently have a try statement in place because I know there will be times where I will actually not be getting back something that was dumped using pickle or what not, so the idea is that it should fail on those and in the except just continue as if the data received was formatted correctly.

The error that is produced when I try to unpickle them for instance is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telnet.py", line 75, in <module>
    d1 = pickle.loads(d1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\r'
```

The pickle.loads never succeeds because pickles is never True...... Any ideas?

EDIT: I have the overall solution. The issue for me was actually not in the file you see in the error, that being telnet.py, but in another file. I didn't realize that the intermediate server was receiving input and changing it. However, after some suggestions, I realized that was what exactly was happening.

Comment: You are sending strings over socket, so check what is sent and received `print msg` on sending side and `print d1`on receiving side. See whether they are the same. If they are the same, you can reproduce the problem without sockets, making it a simpler question. If they are different, you can reproduce the problem without lists and pickles, making this a simpler question again.

Comment: On second thought, `print repr(msg)` and `print repr(d1)`

Comment: I'll give that a go, I mean its pretty clear to me they are not the same, but I think the question is why.

Comment: If they are not the same, you will be able to ask a much simpler question: *Why do I receive "blahblah" when I send "blah blah blah blah"?* ;)

Comment: The question was more geared towards the send and received portions. As I am unfamiliar with them, I am  not 100% sure on their functionality. Having said that, I believe I found the issue.

Comment: So, what was the issue?

Comment: So I think its with an intermediate script that receives input and sends it out. I didn't realize that was happening so I believe it was changing the formatting, then broadcasting. I am going to verify.

Answer (score 0):

My issue actually came from another file. At the time I did not realize that this being a chat server / client was important. However, the chat server was actually sending data back to the client that it formatted.. honestly I don't know how that didn't hit me but thats what happened.